# Unable to call custom extension method

Tags: c#, string, extension-methods, contains

I have tried to make my own extension method like this..

```
static bool Contains(this string source, string toCheck, StringComparison comp)
{
    return source.IndexOf(toCheck, comp) >= 0;
}
```

so that i will be able to find out any substring present in a string irrespective of their Case but while using this extension method in if Condtion i am getting error like this..

> string does not contain a definition for Contains

And

```
if (currentLine.Contains("local", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
}
```

Please help me to resolve this..

Comment: _i am getting error_ What is the error exactly?

Comment: @Liath there is no case-insensitive `Contains` method.

Comment: @Liath Because `Contains` method is Case-sensitive

Comment: @SonerGönül I have updated my post and error is `string does not contain a definition for Contains`

Comment: @user3924730 can't just be declared anywhere. They need to be inside a `static` class which is accessible from where you want to use them. Have you even bothered to read the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb383977.aspx)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your extension method is `public static` and inside a `public static` class.

More specifically, as explained in [How to: Implement and Call a Custom Extension Method (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311042.aspx):

> 1. Define a **static** class to contain the extension method.
>      The class **must be visible to client code**.
> 2. Implement the extension method as a **static** method with **at least the same visibility as the containing class**.
> 3. In the calling code, add a **using** directive to specify the namespace that contains the extension method class.